# is this the correct way of LiveData usage?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am currently applying `Room` + `ViewModel` + `LiveData` to my project.
In my app, there is "obviously" observe data that is needed, but not all.

The code below is example code for `category` data. In my situation, category data does not change and always maintains the same value state (13 categories and content does not change). Categories are data that is loaded from the Database through the `CategoryItemDao` class.

Does category data need to be wrapped with livedata?
Or is there a reason enough to use LiveData in addition to its `observerable` feature?

I've read the guide to LiveData several times, but I do not understand the exact concept.

**CategoryItemDao**

```
@Dao
interface CategoryItemDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM CategoryItem")
    fun getAllCategoryItems(): LiveData<MutableList<CategoryItem>>
}
```

**CategoryRepository**

```
class CategoryRepository(application: Application) {
    private val categoryItemDao: CategoryItemDao
    private val allCategories: LiveData<MutableList<CategoryItem>>

    init {
        val db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application)
        categoryItemDao = db.categoryItemDao()
        allCategories = categoryItemDao.getAllCategoryItems()
    }

    fun getAllCategories() = allCategories
}
```

**CategoryViewModel**

```
class CategoryViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repository = CategoryRepository(application)
    private val allCategories: LiveData<MutableList<CategoryItem>>

    init {
        allCategories = repository.getAllCategories()
    }

    fun getAllCategories() = allCategories
}
```

Comment: Then `LiveData` is not needed for your categories. To sum it up, `LiveData` are data binded with a callback. So any update done in background triggers your callback, independently of anything else.

Comment: If so, is it not desirable to use LiveData for callback only when loading category data initially?

Comment: `LiveData` allows both asynchronized get _plus_ live updates. Depends on your needs. For what I understand, your categories are fixed. Up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine, but you can make a few changes:

1. Change `LiveData<MutableList<CategoryItem>>` to `LiveData<List<CategoryItem>>`. Don't use a `MutableList` unless you really have to. In your case, `List` would work fine.
2. In your `CategoryRepository` instead of fetching in `init`, do it during the `getAllCategories()` call. So change your code like this: `fun getAllCategories() = categoryItemDao.getAllCategoryItems()`
3. Similarly do the same in `CategoryViewModel` as well. Change you code to: `fun getAllCategories() = repository.getAllCategories()`

A common misconception is to use `LiveData` only when the data changes. But that's not true. Your 13 categories may not change, but that's in a database. So if you were to accomplish this without a `LiveData` you have to query the DB and populate the view in the main thread, or you need to wrap this around in a background thread. But if you do this via `LiveData`, you get the Asynchronous Reactive way of coding for free. Whenever possible, try to make your view observe a `LiveData`.